# MPE versus MAP estimates

Tags: bayesian, estimators, decision-theory

In my class notes both MPE (Minimum Probability of Error) and MAP (Maximum Aposteriori Probability) estimators are shown as:

$$h_{MPE}(\mathbf x) = posterior\ mode = arg\ max_{y\in Y}p(y|\mathbf x)$$
$$h_{MAP}(\mathbf x) = posterior\ mode = arg\ max_{y\in Y}p(y|\mathbf x)$$

These have the same formula, so what's the difference? Do they have a different context? Do you just follow this same formula to determine either?

Comment: If I were you, I'd ask your instructor.

Comment: I guess Mininum Probability of Error, Maximum Probable Explanation and Maximum a Posteriori are talking about the same mechanism.